# Convert string to mixed case in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, regex

There are few strings that are being fetched in an array of objects in Angular JS. The values will look like `us-east-1` or `uk-west-5` .

I want to convert each and every string to a mixed case like `US-East-1` or `UK-West-5`.

I know I can achieve the same by `splitting the strings by - and then to convert to toUpperCase() for the first item in array and then to convert only the first letter of the second item item in the array`.

But is there any other feasible solution ?

How about a regex ?  Can someone explain how to use the same ?

Comment: I think regEx are used only to find if given string is matching the given condition or not. We can't use regEx in this scenario. My suggestion is we have to go with Angular filters.

Answer (score 1):

This Should Work.

Search by:

```
(\w+-)(\w)(\w+)
```

Replace with:

```
\U$1\U$2\L$3
```

Explanation:

```
\U => Uppercase
\L => Lowercase
```

Input:

```
us-east-1 or uk-west-5
```

Output:

```
US-East-1 or UK-West-5
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/rzBTpo/1